# Woocommerce - Remove Invoice-id on transaction details (Paypal)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I'm using Wordpress for my Website. I have attached a few plugins for processing purchase content on my website. I have installed the **WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway** plugin.
Now I want to remove Invoice-id in transaction details on Paypal.

[image: See picture]

Answer (score 0):

For this unusual customization, you will need to edit the code of the WooCommerce PayPal plugin you are using, so that it does not transmit the invoice variable to PayPal.